# Mutation Testing Tool for Android

Tags: android, testing, mutation-testing

I'm very interested in Mutation Testing, so I've tried some tools like mujava and this tool worked well with Java code.
I've also read that applying mutation testing on Android isn't trivial.

So, my question is, does anyone know a tool or a way to perform mutation testing for Android code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: PIT works with java, so it should be fine for android. Check my article with an intro to PIT: https://pedrorijo.com/blog/intro-mutation/

Answer (score 7):

You can check [PIT](http://pitest.org/) (aka pitest). Since 0.32 it should work with Roboeletric. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337222/313516).

**Update**: As of 2016 there is a port of my PIT Gradle plugin for [Android](https://github.com/koral--/gradle-pitest-plugin).